# User Authentication in Laravel 5 + AngularJs Without JWT

Tags: php, angularjs, json, laravel-5.1

I am working for an application that will have a Laravel based back-end and laravel + angularJs based front-end.

I have completed about 40% in back-end, now I need to implement the front-end, but I am not getting a `best practice` for that.

**I have tried with login page but I am unable to get the `errors and responses` in json.** I have checked in request, it shows me the login page with error in response.

I have searched a lot for that, and find the solution `JWT` for that.

**Is there any other way to do that, so that I can get all responses and errors in json?**

Answer (score 1):

Your title suggests that you don't want using JWT because you can't catch exceptions :-)

You have to abstract your problem, or better: convert it to a challenge.

Let's begin:

The JWT package has different exceptions, e.g. token blacklisted, enz. So what's your task? To catch that exception! Yeah, so what? Yes, you can return that json to your view.

Below a good example from the JWT site

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{
    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

The method above returns json. To display this information in your view, it's an AngularJS issue and not a JWT issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am looking for any inbuilt functionality in laravel 5 by using that I can get all errors and responses in json form if possible. I do not want to use any third party tool for that :)